# Prove $Y_S$ is integrable if $Y$ is a supermartingale and $S$ is a bounded stopping time.

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Given a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \{\mathscr{F_n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, \mathbb{P})$,

let $Y = ({Y_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a/an $(\{\mathscr{F_n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, \mathbb{P})$-supermartingale.

> Prove $Y_S$ is integrable if $Y$ is a supermartingale and $S$ is a
>   bounded stopping time.

So far all I was able to show is that $Y_{S \wedge n}$ is integrable and $E[Y_S] \le E[Y_0]$.

Hints pls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Since $S$ is a bounded stopping time, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $S(\omega) \leq N$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$. Show that $$\mathbb{E}(|Y_S|) = \sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb{E}(|Y_k| 1_{\{S=k\}}).$$
2. Conclude $$\mathbb{E}(|Y_S|) \leq \sum_{k=0}^N \mathbb{E}(|Y_k|) \leq (N+1) \max_{k=0,\ldots,N} \mathbb{E}(|Y_k|)<\infty.$$

Note that this holds for any stochastic process $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ (we do not need the supermartingale property).

Comment: Thanks saz. Why does that hold for any stochastic process? I think we need supermartingale for the last inequality. Since $Y$ is a supermartingale, $Y_k$'s are integrable.

Comment: @BCLC Yeah sure ... otherwise we can hardly expect that the claim holds true (because $S=n$ is, for fixed $n$, an admissible choice). What I mean by supermartingale property is the fact that $\mathbb{E}(Y_n \mid \mathcal{F}_k) \leq Y_k$ for $k \leq n$.

Comment: Very useful hints! I 'adapted' them to prove that $X_{S\wedge t}$ is integrable, when $X_t$ is also integrable.